# How can I replay Bayonetta 1's tutorial?

Tags: bayonetta

When playing Bayonetta's prologue for the first time, the game provides interactive demonstrations of Bayonetta's moves as a form of tutorial. These scenes are automatically skipped when relaying the level.

Is there any way to replay the tutorial without starting a new save file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the posts in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/946346-bayonetta/52956633), no, there's no way to replay the tutorial outside of starting a new save file.

However, by pressing the Select button during loading screens, you can practice.

> During any loading screen you can press select to stay in that mode.
>
> the game will conduct you to te tutorial to perform this moves just before enter the battle, **after that there are no more tutorials the only way is to hit the back button in the loading screen during chapters.**

Comment: What is the "Select" button for PC?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a touch late, and I'm not sure if this is applicable to other versions of this game, but on the Nintendo Switch version you can do:

- Options > Display Settings > Tutorial: toggle [Off]

Save your changes and exit.

Then:

- Options > Display Settings > Tutorial: toggle [On]

Save your changes and exit again.

The tutorial seems to reset and play out exactly one time after this switch is toggled. If you complete the Tutorial and replay the Prologue without performing this reset, the Tutorial will not take place.

That said, it also seems that if you never completely finish the Tutorial (such as quitting to the Chapter Select screen during the ragdoll training) then it will replay in its entirety upon restarting the Prologue.

Comment: Quick update/correction to this: after toggling the option off/on, the tutorial seems to play out in its entirety (again, this is on Nintendo Switch) even during repeated plays of the Prologue. In fact, I could not get the Tutorial to go away again until I toggled it [Off] in the display options. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

So it did take me a while to figure out how to enter practice mode.

1. Backup your save game before starting a **new game** to just replay Bayonetta 1's tutorial. The tutorial **doesn't include the bought move-set**, and starting new game will overwrite your current save. Actually, I did start a new game when I didn't know how to access practice mode, but at least Tutorial has an opponent for you to beat.
   [image: Bayonetta Tutorial]
2. The key to enter Practice Mode is **Game Menu** key - **Tab** for PC & **Back** for XBox360 controller. I didn't own an XBox360 controller so it did take me a while to figure out the Back/Select button (I thought it was Backspace/Left arrow/Enter on PC, silly me)
3. When the Loading screen (which is Practice Mode) is appearing, **do not** close your eyes and **spam** **Game Menu** key (Tab key in my case). This key work as toggle so the first hit, you're in, the second hit, you're out. Just hit one time and the word **Practice Mode** appear and you know you're in.

[image: Bayonetta - Enter practice mode]